# Is it possible to use RxJava in a libgdx Android project?

Tags: java, libgdx, rx-java

Is it possible to use RxJava in a libgdx Android project? Is there any incompatible issues in terms of libraries, threading, etc. that will make it not work or hard to integrate?

Answer (score 3):

I know people have experimented with it. I have not used RxJava in a libgdx project but I can't see why it shouldn't work.

Some examples:

[rxjava-libgdx](https://github.com/jmhofer/rxjava-libgdx)

[example](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=rxjava-libgdx-master/src/main/java/rx/GdxObservable.java)